# Git diff ignore

Tags: git, autotools

Is it somehow possible to ignore certain files during git diff? I'm specifically interested in filtering out Makefile.in, Makefile, configure (and all that auto-generated crap).

Comment: You could add them all to your `.gitignore` file; if they are auto-generated, does it make sense to store them in your source control system?

Comment: I'm not storing them there, that's the whole problem. If I would I would just take them out, easy-peasy.

This is upstream problem. But I need to diff two different upstream branches and all I get is just tons of this auto-generated junk. Pretty much impossible to do any real comparison work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try passing a list of files to `git diff`, and it will execute the diff only on those files.

Depending on how your code is setup, it can be as easy as:

```
git diff otherbranchname -- src/     # only give me diffs from src/
```

or as unsightly/complex as:

```
git diff otherbranchname -- $( git ls-files |
    perl -lne'next if /(?:[mM]akefile(?:\.in)?|configure|whateverelse)/;print' )
# diff all files which don't match the pattern
```

Depending on whether the files you want to ignore are managed by Git in the current branch or not, you'll need to replace the `git ls-files` with a `find *`; use instead a `find .` and add `|.git` to the Perl expression.

Tailor this as you see fit, possibly using the directories / file names you *know* you'd like to diff, rather than using the `git ls-files` or `find`.

Comment: Oh, this is just pure awesome :-D Thanks

Comment: Untracked files won't show up in the diff, though - I'd think `ls-files` would always be plenty, unless for some reason you *want* a diff for some untracked files.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar solution (add to `.git/config`):

```
[alias]
    mydiff = !git diff -- $(git diff --name-only | grep -Ev "([mM]akefile|configure)")
```

Then run it with:

```
git mydiff
```

Note that `git diff --name-only` is better than `git ls-files` because it will pass a shorter list of files to `git diff`, since only files that are modified will be included. I've run into trouble with exceeding the maximum number of arguments in large projects when using `git ls-files`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding gitignore and autotools integration, you might be interested in git.mk: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2009-April/msg00211.html

Answer (score 0):

As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39937070/281545) you can use an `exclude` pathspec magic

```
git diff -- . ':(exclude)Makefile*' ':(exclude)configure'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the content of the diffs but still do care whether the files have changed, this is a job for `.gitattributes` and the `diff` attribute. Say you have a directory structure like

```
repo
  repo/foo
    repo/foo/Makefile
  repo/bar
    repo/bar/Makefile.in
    repo/bar/baz
      repo/bar/baz/Makefile.in
```

If you want to ignore all three Makefiles, create `repo/.gitattributes` as:

```
Makefile* -diff
```

If you want to ignore `bar/Makefile.in` but not the others, create `repo/bar/.gitattributes` as

```
Makefile.in -diff
```

but also `repo/bar/baz/.gitattributes` as

```
Makefile.in diff
```

For more detail of what can be done with `.gitattributes`, see [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes); my examples are drawn from [theirs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_examples), made specific to diff.

(h/t to [user3589608's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3589608/user3589608) [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/want-to-exclude-file-from-git-diff/53873491#53873491))