# Exclude file from "git diff"

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I am trying to exclude a file (`db/irrelevant.php`) from a Git diff. I have tried putting a file in the `db` subdirectory called `.gitattributes` with the line `irrelevant.php -diff`
and I have also tried creating a file called `.git/info/attributes` containing `db/irrelevant.php`.

In all cases, the `db/irrelevant.php` file is included in the diff as a Git binary patch. What I want is for the changes to that file to be ignore by the diff command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 575, accepted):

OMG, drivers and [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to exclude a lousy file? Since [Git 1.9 something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/281545) you can:

```bash
git diff -- . ':(exclude)db/irrelevant.php' ':(exclude)db/irrelevant2.php'
```

(On Windows, replace the single quotes `'` by double quotes `"`.)

Ah, elegance! See the quoted answer and for details [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39937070/281545) by @torek.

Comment: NOTE: If you want to exclude a specific file name you have to prefix with asterisk, different from the `.gitignore` file syntax. E.g. `:!*shrinkwrap.yaml` instead of `:!shrinkwrap.yaml`.

Comment: Exclude more files, E.g. I have *.min.css and *.min.js files to avoid from the git diff. So, I use the command `git diff -- . ':(exclude)*.min.js' ':(exclude)*.min.css'`

Comment: **windows syntax** : `git diff -- . ":(exclude)db/irrelevant.php"` (double quotes instead of single quotes)

Comment: Thank you! Such an esoteric syntax.. I have to look it up every time.

Comment: @cnlevy or no quotes! `git diff -- . :(exclude)db/irrelevant.php`

Comment: `git diff -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json'` -- for a (probably) very common case here's command line to copy-paste.

Comment: Would it be possible to add this co .gitconfig file so `git diff` always runs with this by default?

Comment: For those wondering why it doesn't work for them, the "." is required (or some pathspec). Just plain "git diff ':!yarn.lock" will still diff yarn.lock. You need "git diff . ':!yarn.lock'".  Elegance indeed... :-/

Comment: @dominikduda [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias). but you can `git config alias.diff2 "diff -- :/ ':(exclude,top)src/ignore-me.txt'"` and use `git diff2`

Comment: Please note that the '.' is important. The '':(exclude)' syntax works only if there is an incluse specification 'the '.'
If you forget this, you have a error that looks like:
`fatal: There is nothing to exclude from by :(exclude) patterns.`

Comment: `"` is only needed for cmd, not Powershell.

Comment: `:(exclude)` can be shortened to `:!` (I think). It should be possible to find support for it in the documentation. It is also used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/exclude-file-from-git-diff/48259275#48259275). And supported by a statement in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths/21079437#21079437). [Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

Answer (score 150):

This method is shorter than the accepted answers.

```bash
git diff 987200fbfb 878cee40ba -- ':!*.cs'
```

For more information about the different inclusion/exclusion possibilities read [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685007/making-git-log-ignore-changes-for-certain-paths/21079437#21079437)

Comment: Be aware that the filter only applies to all files below your current directory.

Comment: This was the best answer. I was able to simplify it a bit more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58845608/3886183

Comment: I would remove the --stat part, or at least explain what it does, since none of the other answers include it.

Comment: The stat flag shows you the files and their diff totals, which allows you to check easily if the filter worked the way you intended.

Comment: @mix3d Removed `--stat` since it's irrelevant (and perhaps misleading) to the answer.

Comment: Can you exclude two extensions this way?

Comment: Ok, I see ```git diff -- ':!*.cs' ':!*.js' ``` Thanks

Comment: What are the limitations of these wildcards? Must they be in the beginning or the end of the string or path element? They certainly ***don't*** work in the middle of the string or path element. For example, "`keyboards/keychron/c*_pro`" will *** ***not*** *** match "`keyboards/keychron/c2_pro`"

Comment: In the middle works fine for me. Make sure you escape properly in your command line shell, etc.

Answer (score 90):

### Simplest answer

```bash
git diff ':!db/irrelevant.php'
```

It's just `':!<path>'` after your diff command. The diff command can be as complicated as you like, and you can use wildcards like `*.min.js` or add multiple excludes (space separate the quoted blocks) if you want.

Comment: Thanks! works great for `git log -p` as well. As in: `git log -p ':!package-lock.json'`

Comment: The most-effective answer for me. Excludes only the specific file in question (and nice tip on 'git log -p', too @David). Quite effictive for what our team calls "git mid-edit saves" when you want to "backup save" a large set of untested (and therefore uncertified by the developer) git edits without making a more-official "commit"; like this (in a `.bash_profile` or some such): `gd_file="./2-git-diff-mid-edit-save.diff.txt"; alias git_mid_edit_save="git diff ':!$gd_file' > $gd_file; git add $gd_file; git commit -m 'mid-edit save'; git push -u"`

Comment: Latest version of my immediately-above code here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnnyutahh/e8cfb515fb65635dca520117477456b8/raw

Comment: single quote is invalid in window
`git show ceef58a ":!stuuuudy.ipynb"` worked in my case, thankyou!

Answer (score 81):

You could set up a custom diff driver with a no op command and assign it to those files that should be ignored.

**Create a repository specific diff driver** with this command

```
git config diff.nodiff.command /bin/true
```

or for all your repos with `--global`.

(If `/bin/true` doesn't exist in MacOS, alternatives would be using `/usr/bin/true` or `echo`).

**Then, assign the new diff driver to those files you want ignored** in your `.git/info/attributes` file.

```
irrelevant.php    diff=nodiff
```

If this state is supposed to be shared with other developers you could use `.gitattributes` instead of `.git/info/attributes` and share the `git config` command with your peers (through a documentation file or something).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - as described in http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/10/17/3711254 I edited  

~/.gitconfig  


adding:  

`[diff "nodiff"]`  

`    command = /bin/true`  

and I then created a file called .git/info/attributes into which I added:  
`irrelevant.php diff=nodiff`

Comment: This answer worked much better for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016798/excluding-files-from-git-diff

Comment: Interestingly this approach does not work with `git diff --stat`.  In that case, one could use `git diff ... | diffstat` as a workaround.

Comment: @Michael that link appears to be borked, is there another?

Comment: just an addition: if you want to force git diff to display it anyway, use `--no-ext-diff`

Comment: It works! In a Windows command prompt, I used `true` in place of `/bin/true`.  (`echo` had a weird effect on the diff, getting hung up momentarily when I hit `q` to exit the diff.)

Comment: `git diff --exit-code` will exit with `1` with this used, as if there were differences.

Answer (score 40):

You can also use [filterdiff](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/filterdiff.1.php) program of the [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) program collection to exclude some parts of a diff. For example:

```
git diff | filterdiff -p 1 -x db/irrelevant.php
```

Comment: Note that `-p`, from the manpage(1), is "-p n, --strip-match=n When matching, ignore the first n components of the pathname." It took me a while to catch that `-p 1` was removing the `db` part from the OP's path. If you just want to specify a filename and ignore all path/dir possibilities, you can use `-p 99`.

Comment: The first link is broken: it times out (after several minutes) - *"The connection has timed out. The server at www.linuxmanpages.com is taking too long to respond."*

Answer (score 38):

Really good answer from [KurzedMetal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236871/kurzedmetal) for what I needed to do, which was ability to see that the file has changed, but not to generate the diff, which could have been huge, in my case.

But a colleague of mine suggested approach that was even simpler and worked for me:

adding `.gitattributes` file in the directory where the file to be ignored by `git diff` resides with the following content:

`file-not-to-diff.bin -diff`

That still lets `git status` "see" if the file changed. `git diff` will also "see" that the file changed, but it will not generate the `diff`.

That `.bin` extension for the file in the example was deliberate. I do realize that this is the default behavior of git for binary files, and it does not require special handling with `.gitattributes`. But in my case, these files were recognized as text files by git and "file" utility, and this did the trick.

Comment: Yes! This is neat and tidy, it doesn't hide that anything changed, but won't show you ugly-ass `*.min.js` files and the like. This is excellent, the best answer IMHO.

Comment: Awesome answer. clear and simple.. Kudos

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Git Extensions on Windows by default automatically shows diffs for .pdf files which is often quite time consuming. This allowed me to disable the diff specifically for the .pdf, but still easily commit the most recent version.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It really should: no one wants to have to type a bunch of arguments every time they `git diff`.  This solutions let's you fix it once and forget about the issue forever.

Comment: If you have a per-developer config file (i.e. `.sbtopts` in my case) and you want to use `--assume-unchanged` but don't want it showing up in diffs for local changes - this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 15):

This one-line solution requires no other utils/downloads:

```bash
git diff `git status -s |grep -v ^\ D |grep -v file/to/exclude.txt |cut -b4-`
```

Where `file/to/exclude.txt` is the name of the file you would like to exclude, of course.

Edit: credit [ksenzee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281622/ksenzee) for fixing deleted files breaking the diff.

Comment: I am trying to adapt your one liner to `git diff --stat master` without much success - could you help ?

Answer (score 13):

### Relative to the git root directory

`git diff` accepts an optional exclude

```bash
git diff -- ":(exclude)thingToExclude"
```

### You might want to add some wild cards

```bash
git diff -- ":(exclude)*/thingToExclude/*"
```

### Target specific file types

```bash
git diff -- ":(exclude)*/$1/*.png"
```

#### Or drop a little script for your dotfiles

#### Such as `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`

```bash
gde() {
    # git diff exclude files or folders 
    # usage: 
    # gde fileOrFolderNameToExclude
    git diff -- ":(exclude)*/$1/*"
}
```

Comment: this just does not work for me, I get no diff at all, with both syntaxes, using (exclude) or !. I have git 2.21.0

Comment: You can git diff either unstaged or staged files. If you have git added them they become staged. If they are staged you can do ```git diff --staged``` Hope this helps you.

Comment: Syntactically, what is the colon doing?

Answer (score 8):

Building on existing answers, if you want to exclude a file pattern no matter where it is in the directory, use the corresponding [git pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) value of `**`:

```bash
git diff -- ':!**/yarn.lock'
```

Answer (score 3):

I do the following:

```
git add *pattern_to_exclude*
git diff
git reset HEAD .
```

I know it's not an elegant solution and it sometimes canot be used (eg. if you already have stuff staged) , but it does the trick without having to type a complicated command

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, you can exclude what you want using standard unix commands, those commands are available under git bash even under windows environment. 
Below example shows how to exclude diff for pom.xml files, first check diff to master only for filenames, then using 'grep -v' exclude files which you don't want and then run again diff to master with prepapred list:

```
git diff master `git diff --name-only master | grep -v pom.xml`
```

Answer (score 2):

My workaround

```
git add .
git reset <list of files to ignore>
git diff --cached
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Ben Roux's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/exclude-file-from-git-diff/10421413#10421413), but I am sharing anyway:

```bash
git status --porcelain | grep -v $PATTERN_TO_EXCLUDE | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git diff
```

or, if the changes have already be committed locally:

```bash
git diff --name-only origin/master | grep -v $PATTERN_TO_EXCLUDE | xargs git diff origin/master
```

Examples:

```bash
git status --porcelain | grep -v docs | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git diff origin/master

git diff --name-only origin/master | grep -v docs | xargs git diff origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this only to visually inspect the diff, a visual diff tool (like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)) will let you do it with a short command that's easy to remember.

First, set up a diff tool if you haven't already.

```
$ git config --global diff.tool = meld
```

Then, you can run a directory diff.

```
$ git difftool --dir-diff
```

You'll be able to browse diffs (by file) in Meld (or your tool of choice). Simply don't open the file you want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git diff remote/master..master --name-only -- ':!README.rst'
```

Gave me (git version 2.11.0)

```
fatal: There is nothing to exclude from by :(exclude) patterns.
Perhaps you forgot to add either ':/' or '.' ?
```

```sh
git diff remote/master..master --name-only -- './*' ':!README.rst'
```

Worked nicely, source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084612/5155484