# How to exclude certain directories/files from git grep search

Tags: git, grep

Is there a way to exclude certain paths/directories/files when searching a git repository using `git grep`? Something similar to the `--exclude` option in the normal `grep` command?

I need to use `git grep` because using `grep` directly runs too slowly on large git repositories.

Comment: Doing it on bash would be a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Comment: This feature was added in 1.9.0 [see my answer below](/a/30084612/436287)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not possible, but [has been discussed recently](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-grep-while-excluding-files-in-a-blacklist-td7195648.html). Proposed workaround in link:

> You can put `*.dll` to .gitignore file then `git grep --exclude-standard`.

EDIT see [onlynone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084612), since git 1.9.0 it's possible.

Comment: This used to be true but no longer, it is now possible in git. See what should be the real answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30084612/1391445

Answer (score 298):

In git 1.9.0 the "magic word" `exclude` was added to `pathspec`s. So if you want to search for `foobar` in every file except for those matching `*.java` you can do:

```
git grep foobar -- ':(exclude)*.java'
```

Or using the `!` "short form" for exclude:

```
git grep foobar -- ':!*.java'
```

Note that in git versions up to v2.12, when using an exclude `pathspec`, you must have at least one "inclusive" `pathspec`. In the above examples you'd want to add `./*` (recursively include everything under the current directory) somewhere after the `--` as well. In git v2.13 this restriction was lifted and `git grep foobar -- ':!*.java'` works without the `./*`.

There's a good reference for all the "magic words" allowed in a `pathspec` at [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pathspec) (or just `git help glossary`).

Comment: `git grep clock.gettime -- './*' ':!arch/**' ':!drivers/**'` to exclude multiple entire directories. I don't think it prevents recursion though.

Comment: For frequent use, you can make a git alias with the exclusions: `git config alias.mygrep '!git grep "$@" -- "${GIT_PREFIX}/*" ":!*.java*" #'`. Then just `git mygrep foobar`. (Using alias [shell # trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39523506/647002) and [current dir](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22039008/647002).)

Comment: the problem i cant solve with this solution is that the reported paths of the files are relative to the WC root. So, if i'm in a sub dir of the WC,  i cant just use the path of found file(s) as-is (e.g. for less) but have to junc common paths. Is there a solution to this (w/o having to emply sed myself) ? [git bash on win7]

Comment: @elonderin this solution has nothing to do with how the matched files are reported. But I just tried a `git grep` and `git ls-files` from subdirectories and both report filenames relative to the current directory (even when you use the `':(top)'` include pathspec). Both commands have the `--full-name` option to report names relative to the root, but that's off by default.

Comment: Or `git grep foobar -- './*' ':^*.java'`, since `:!` and `:^` are synonyms of `:(exclude)`

Comment: I don't use git aliases so I made a bash function, but possibly a git alias is better https://gist.github.com/cmdcolin/04e2378b60f4457a41904c659368066f

Comment: @YogeshwerSharma Do you mind accepting this answer instead of the outdated one?

Comment: I'm using git 2.19 and a simpler syntax than the one posted above that works is just: git grep foobar ':!*.java'

Comment: could `':(exclude)`  applied for specific files?

Answer (score 66):

**Update:** For git >= 1.9 there is native support for exclude patterns, see [onlyone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30084612/396967).

This may seem backwards, but you can pass a list of files not matching your exclude pattern to `git grep` like this:

```
git grep <pattern> -- `git ls-files | grep -v <exclude-pattern>`
```

`grep -v` returns every path *not* matching `<exclude-pattern>`. Note that `git ls-files` also takes a `--exclude` parameter, but that is only applied to *untracked files*.

Comment: Thanks for this! Git grep is so much faster than ack & co but not being able to exclude arbitrary paths was a bit too inconvenient so to speak :)

Comment: Unfortunately my repo has a lot of files. When I try @kynan's approach I get: "-bash: /usr/bin/git: Argument list too long"

Comment: This should solve both the "Argument list too long" problem of Benissimo and my problem with filename caracters interpreted by bash (like []) or filenames containing spaces in the repository:
git ls-files | grep -v <exclue-pattern> | xargs -d '\n' git grep <pattern> --

Comment: Check onlynone's answer, it's possibly to do this entirely within (modern versions of) git now.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This answer still applies to git versions prior to 1.9. I've added a note referring to onlyone's answer.

Answer (score 23):

You can mark files or directories as binary by creating an attributes file in your repository, e.g.

```
$ cat .git/info/attributes 
directory/to/ignore/*.* binary
directory/to/ignore/*/*.* binary
another_directory/to/also/ignore/*.* binary
```

Matches in binary files are listed without the including line, e.g.

```
$ git grep "bar"
Binary file directory/to/ignore/filename matches
other_directory/other_filename:      foo << bar - bazz[:whatnot]
```

Comment: This is actually a great answer.

Comment: I found that `dir-i-wanted-to-ignore/**/* binary` did the trick.

Comment: Best answer. Can also be committed to the repo by using `.gitattributes` instead of local `.git/info/attributes`.

Answer (score 2):

With the example by @kynan as base I made this script and put it in my path (`~/bin/`) as  `gg`. It does use `git grep` but avoids some specified filetypes.

In our repo its a lot of images so I have excluded the imagefiles, and this takes the serchtime down to 1/3 if I search the whole repo. But the script could easily be modified to exclude other filestypes or geleralpatterns.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                    
#                                                                              
# Wrapper of git-grep that excludes certain filetypes.                         
# NOTE: The filetypes to exclude is hardcoded for my specific needs.           
#                                                                              
# The basic setup of this script is from here:                                 
#   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14226610/42580                                  
# But there is issues with giving extra path information to the script         
# therefor I crafted the while-thing that moves path-parts to the other side   
# of the '--'.                                                                 

# Declare the filetypes to ignore here                                         
EXCLUDES="png xcf jpg jpeg pdf ps"                                             

# Rebuild the list of fileendings to a good regexp                             
EXCLUDES=`echo $EXCLUDES | sed -e 's/ /\\\|/g' -e 's/.*/\\\.\\\(\0\\\)/'`      

# Store the stuff that is moved from the arguments.                            
moved=                                                                         

# If git-grep returns this "fatal..." then move the last element of the        
# arg-list to the list of files to search.                                     
err="fatal: bad flag '--' used after filename"                                 
while [ "$err" = "fatal: bad flag '--' used after filename" ]; do              
    {                                                                          
        err=$(git grep "$@" -- `git ls-files $moved | grep -iv "$EXCLUDES"` \  
            2>&1 1>&3-)                                                        
    } 3>&1                                                                     

    # The rest of the code in this loop is here to move the last argument in   
    # the arglist to a separate list $moved. I had issues with whitespace in   
    # the search-string, so this is loosely based on:                          
    #   http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-preserving-whitespace-using-set-and-eval
    x=1                                                                        
    items=                                                                     
    for i in "$@"; do                                                          
        if [ $x -lt $# ]; then                                                 
            items="$items \"$i\""                                              
        else                                                                   
            moved="$i $moved"                                                  
        fi                                                                     
        x=$(($x+1))                                                            
    done                                                                       
    eval set -- $items                                                         
done                                                                           
# Show the error if there was any                                              
echo $err
```

**Note 1**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978257/extending-git-functionality) it should be possible to name the thing `git-gg` and be able to call it as a regular git command like:

```
$ git gg searchstring
```

But I can not get this working. I created the script in my `~/bin/` and made a the `git-gg` symlink in `/usr/lib/git-core/`.

**Note 2**

The command can not be made into an regular `sh` git-alias since it will then be invoked at the root of the repo. And that is not what I want!