# Could I extend git functionality in my ~/bin/ directory?

Tags: git

As stated in numerous posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10978257/42580) you could extend git by placing a program/script in your PATH. I get it working if I place my script in for example `/usr/local/bin/`. But I what to add commands without being `root`, but if if put it in `~/bin/` it will not be found.

`~/bin/` is in my PATH since its added in my `.bashrc` like this:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:~/bin"
```

I got other stuff as well in my `~/bin/` that I use regularly so the PATH-thing is working for other things!

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only missing piece would be the naming convention:

```
git my-custom-made-extension ... → git-my-custom-made-extension
```

That means you need to have an executable file `~/bin/git-my-custom-made-extension` (no extension, chmod 755)

Plus, don't rely on `~`: the git shell which will execute the script might not have the same `~` as the user who owns the script. PATH should include the full path of the home.

See "[Shell variable expansion in git config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262153/6309)"

Comment: All those things are already in place (obviously since its working when I put the same thing in `/usr/local/bin/` as stated in the Q).

Comment: @UlfR then add to your path the full path of your HOME instead of ~

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks. Why does not the `~/` notation work?