# Can I change the shell used by extended git functionality?

Tags: git, bash, shell

On my systems, putting a shell script `git-foo` in directory `/home/me/mygits` (nothing special about the name) on your path causes the command

```
git foo
```

to evaluate to

```
/bin/sh /home/me/mygits/git-goo
```

I use a lot of bash shell functions in my programming and even though I `export -f` the functions, they don't make it to the shell started up by the git functionality.

I was wondering if there was any way to control what shell gets started when the command that is being executed is a shell script? That may not help in the end, but I'd like to try a few experiments before giving up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use whatever you want (including Perl, Python, etc). Just add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of the script.

Or you can use something like this to find a command in `$PATH` without specifying it at a static path.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: Oh DUH! to me. Thanks.

Comment: To elaborate, use the "whereis" command i.e. "whereis python" to get the path to the executable and then add this after #! in the script.

Comment: @RamanSailopal You can also use `/usr/bin/env` to do that on the fly; added that to the answer.

Comment: These are all correct, but I fear that none will actually help the situation. Each of these is going to start up a new process, not a subshell of the current process. Hence, all exports will be lost.

What I REALLY need is to eval the script in the context of the calling process. But that would involve some type of `exec` call by `git` to pull that off.

I have to take a look at the git code handling all of this, which I can get from another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978257/extending-git-functionality)

Comment: @mpersico: *Hence, all exports will be lost* There is nothing you can do about this: environment variables are strictly hierarchical.  Even a subshell of the current (Git command in C or shell) process does not affect its parent. A few programs, such as `git filter-branch`, deliberately run commands in a way that allows them to affect itself (filter-branch is itself a shell script and uses `eval`) but most assume, and even depend-on, this kind of separation.

Comment: @torek: Yes you are correct. My choices are to stop using the functions, convert them to non-functions or not to covert my git functions to git extended commands.