# Is it possible to ignore certain directories by default when using git grep?

Tags: git, grep

With south in Django we have something like:

```
/app
  /migrations
    .. migration files.
```

Since migration files represent historical structure rather than what's currently in there I would prefer to not search through them each time. Is there some way I can exclude them by default when running `git grep`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10423143/183791

Comment: @dusan maybe not an exact duplicate, but the answer there might be useful here.

Comment: I disagree with duplicate, because this asks _by default_. I don't see a trivial reduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad hack, but it might work for you: create `app/migrations/.gitattributes` with the following content

```
* binary
```

to mark all migrations as binary files and then use `git grep -I` to skip binary files.

If you also want to ignore migrations in diffs you can do so by changing the content of `.gitattributes` to

```
* binary -diff
```

There is [discussion](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-grep-while-excluding-files-in-a-blacklist-td7195648.html) about adding attributes respected by `grep`, so there might be a proper solution one day.

Answer (score 1):

I have an alias `git gr` for `git grep` that enables colors and case insensitivity. You could do this and add excludes. And it's faster to type!

Otherwise, there's no way to change the default behavior of Git commands for the most part, because they are used directly internally.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add excludes", `git grep` doesn't support exclude patterns. Or do you alias `git gr` to a regular `grep` via a `!` alias?

Comment: Hmm. I never noticed that. If you don't care about the blob specific features of `git grep`, I guess you could just use normal grep, and make sure to exclude `.git`.

Comment: You could create an alias with a default list of files to *include* not containing your migrations folder as discussed [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14226610/396967)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution using the `git grep` command alone.

A workaround I can think of is to add the files/folders you want to ignore to the `.gitignore` file ans then execute the command like :

```
git grep --exclude-standard
```

Comment: I can't do that, I need the database migrations in my repo sadly.

Comment: For anyone who's been wondering: while you can add tracked files to `.gitignore`, `--exclude-standard` applies only to untracked files.