# How to do a git diff between branches and exclude one file

Tags: git

This should be simple for someone, i just can't seem to get the right syntax.   The situation is I have checked out one of my colleagues branches and I want to see the difference between this branch and the dev branch however I don't want to see the changes in one particular file (because it's a huge file).  Here is what I have tried:

```
git diff origin/dev ':(exclude)package-lock.json'

git diff ':(exclude)package-lock.json' origin/dev

git diff -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json' origin/dev
```

I know I'm close...

Note... I have been told that this question is a possible duplicate of this one: [Want to exclude file from "git diff"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/want-to-exclude-file-from-git-diff)  however this is not the case.  The accepted answer of that question is this:

```
git diff -- . ':(exclude)db/irrelevant.php'
```

however when i run this command on my system:

```
git diff -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json'
```

I get nothing.  The reason I get nothing is likely due to the fact that in this command It is never specified that I want a diff between my current branch and origin/dev.  What i want is similar to the above answer but also indicating the difference between the current branch and a remote branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to exclude file from "git diff"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/want-to-exclude-file-from-git-diff)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, this is the post i went to to get what i tried already but it doesn't work in my particular case.

Comment: when i run the suggested answer: 'git diff -- . ':(exclude)package-lock.json'  i get no results because i'm not specifying origin/dev anywhere, but I can't figure out how to also specify that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me:

`git diff branchname -- ':(exclude)filename'`

Comment: ding! I knew someone would get this quick...  I will accept this as the answer when the system allows me to do so...

Comment: Really?  doesn't for me; I get an error that there's nothing to exclude from.  May be a difference of versions

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I'm on version 2.7.4.  Both answers here work on mine

Answer (score 2):

You have to list paths last.  You have to have an include path to have exclude paths.  Some of your attempts do each of these, but none do all :)

```
git diff origin/dev -- . ':!/package-lock.json'
```