# How can i skip some files while taking git diff?

Tags: git

I want to skip some files from git diff.
I cannot put them in .gitignore list since i need them and update constantly.

.gitattributes seems to solve this issue for me. But i have no clear idea about how to go about it.

I have tried putting the files after checkin into .gitignore. But it came to my notice that git still considers those files from .gitignore while taking git diff.

I want something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Kirkkt/b86d453b14f2dab78e09), but it does not work with my version of git i.e (git version 2.14.1.windows.1)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/want-to-exclude-file-from-git-diff) talks about skipping files in git diff by passing the files to skip as parameters to git diff command. But if i do this, i have to keep track of all the files. I want to put the skip list in some kind of .git_______ file which git will implicitly use for skipping while taking git diff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to exclude file from “git diff”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/want-to-exclude-file-from-git-diff)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Not exactly!
I want to keep the list of all the files to be skipped while taking git-diff in a separate file like .gitattributes
This removes my headache of keeping track of which files am i skipping while taking git diff as mentioned in above link where he is passing the list of files to skip as parameters

Comment: That "something like this" you linked has been in Git since long before 2.14.

Comment: @jthill yes! could figure that out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can add all the files to skip in .gitattributes file in the root of git repository

on windows use this command `git config diff.nodiff.command C:/"Program\ Files"/Git/usr/bin/true` and on mac use `git config diff.nodiff.command usr/bin/true`
to set git config.

.gitattributes contents can be as follows:

```
Readme.md diff=nodiff
xzy.txt diff=nodiff
```

Then this should skip Readme.md and xyz.txt file changes while taking git diff!

Comment: Also, you can have a repo-local attributes file in `.git/info/attributes`.