# Run a script to parse YAML when React app compiles

Tags: reactjs, json, build, yaml, build-script

### My Problem

I have a ReactJS website that parses a JSON file (stored in the `src` folder) to render content. I recently attempted to use a YAML file instead because of YAML's richer abilities (supporting Markdown, for example).

Because React must load and parse YAML asynchronously, this change complicated my codebase and degraded my app's performance (e.g., content flickers).

### My Plan

Instead of rewriting my components and slowing down my app, I've written a script to convert my YAML file into a JSON file. This way, I can have the best of both worlds: the richer abilities of YAML and the simple implementation of JSON.

### My Question

What's the best way to make React run this script when the app is built? My web host rebuilds my app every time I push a change, so hopefully this can be activated via `package.json` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My Solution

I solved the problem using [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml). I even found a way to make it work with Fast Refresh.

**./src/[PATH]/yaml-convert.js:**

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');

const args = process.argv.slice(2);

switch (args[0]) {
  case 'watch':
    watch();
    break;
  default:
    convert();
}

function watch() {
  fs.watch('./src/[PATH]/myData.yaml', function (event, filename) {
    require('child_process').fork('./src/[PATH]/yaml-convert.js');
  });
}

function convert() {
  try {
    const json = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('./src/[PATH]/myData.yaml', 'utf8'));
    fs.writeFileSync('./src/[PATH]/myData.json', JSON.stringify(json));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

**package.json:**
(note the `-- watch` argument and the single `&` in the *dev* command)

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "serve -s build",
  "dev": "npm run yaml-convert -- watch & react-scripts start",
  "build": "npm run yaml-convert && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "yaml-convert": "node ./src/[PATH]/yaml-convert.js"
}
...
```

And to [keep `git diff` tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873491/559415)...

**.gitattributes:**

```
/src/[PATH]/myData.json -diff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an empty object that will store the converted data from the YAML, and use an if statement to check if the former object length is >0 then render what you want from the data (and if not, render a placeholder)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to avoid this entirely by converting the file to JSON at compile time. This will allow me to use the faster and simpler JSON parsing.